# shortcut to open method dropdown in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to open the method popup that shows up when you click the navigation-bar in XCode.

is there a way to do this by using a shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The shortcut is ^6 (a.k.a. Control+6). To change the shortcut go to Xcode-->Preferences...->Key Bindings, and look for the View Menu list. It is called "Standard editor -> Show Document items"

Comment: please tell me if you know, how i can jump to following method implementation.

Comment: Control+6 opens the menu at the method you are editing. The down/up arrows will move up and down the list, then hit enter. A reason not to change the shortcut is that ^1 and above do useful things (e.g., ^5 is go to file in folder).

Comment: Horrible shortcut for a much used feature for me so I mapped it to Cmd + O and overwrote the File Open shortcut which I rarely do once I'm in a project.

Comment: I have wanted this for years. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

**control+6**. Pres control and 6 together. :)

Comment: wow, horrible for my fingers. do you have the name it is called in the key-bindings settings, so i could change it?

Comment: Standard Editor > Show Document Items