# Outline or list of declared fields, methods and functions in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm an Android developer and started learning Swift and XCode recently. I couldn't find the outline of declared variables, methods. I searched SO and web for list, outline, and structure of declared functions but i got no result. You can see this list on the right of the Eclipse panel as outline and available as structure in Android Studio.

If there is no outline for list of declared, how can i move to definition of a specific function or method if i do not remember the name also if i do.

How do you manage a class hierarchy when a class gets more than 20 functions or methods for instance?

Comment: adding to below answers, might be useful for @Fatih.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100364/shortcut-to-open-method-dropdown-in-xcode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[image]

To go to this view, simply click on the rightmost thing on the bar just above the code editor:

[image]

In the above picture you should click on "No Selection".

Note that it shows you the "sections" of your code, like "Core Data stack". This can be done by writing comments like this:

```
// MARK: - XXX XXX XXX
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly i was looking for. Creating sections with // MARK is probably will be quite useful for me. I also wonder is there any tutorials or page shows tips about features like this?

Comment: @FatihOzcan I guess you just need to play around with Xcode more... or you can look for Xcode tips on google. Also note there are Xcode plugins that you can install. They might help as well.

Comment: Hey @Sweeper, do you know how to see static methods as well?

Comment: The breadcrumbs at the top of the editor pane (which is what my answer is about) should show static members too. OTOH, I've found that the symbol navigator mentioned in B25Dec's answer doesn't show static members for some reason.

Comment: What is keyboard shortcut for that?

Comment: @AtsuoSakakihara To open the breadcrumbs, it's control + 6. If you are referring to the symbol navigator in B25Dec's answer, then it's command + 3.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can find this option in below image. Search your class name and it will display all your written function on it. Both way will work.  [image]

Comment: This answer was actually what was in my mind when i asked the question, since it most resembles to Android IDE counterpart. I really couldn't decide which answer should be accepted and probably accepted this if this was first. I upvote this answer too.

Comment: Thank you no prob. I also upvote him :) happy coding